# Is this set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ closed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convexity, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a convex set (in my case $X$ is infinite dimensional too) and for each $ i \in \{1,2,\dots,d \} $, let $f_{i}: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be convex functions where $C_{i} := \{ f_{i}(x) : x \in X \} = [a_{i}, b_{i}]$ - closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$.

Does that mean the set $C := \{ \left(f_{1}(x), f_{2}(x),\dots, f_{d}(x)\right) : x \in X   \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d} $ is closed?

It is certainly bounded and convex.  But I don't know if it is closed.

Note that the set $C$ is clearly not equal to $[a_{1},b_{1}] \  \times \dots \times [a_{d},b_{d}]$.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! It seems that this question isn't actually in research mathematics. Why not ask it on Math Stackexchange instead?

Comment: This question is important for my research in mathematics though..... 

But I did also ask on Math Stackexchange too.

Comment: ok to be more specific, $X$ is the space of all probability measures $\mathbb{Q}$ that are absolutely continuous with respect to some underlying probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ and whose Radon-Nikodym derivate is bounded above by $M$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

So each $x \in X$ is a probability measure $Q$.  And the functions $f_{i}$ are expectations $\mathbb{E}^{x}[Y_{i}]$ where $Y_{i}$ are integrable random variables wrt the underlying probability measure $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2984651/442, as mentioned.